# Print a tupe key dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the last and first names of the authors being the key, and the book, quantity, and price being the values. I want to print them out sorted in alphabetical order by the author name, and then by the book name.

```
The author is: Dickens, Charles
The title is: Hard Times
The qty is: 7
The price is: 27.00
----
The author is: Shakespeare, William
The title is: Macbeth
The qty is: 3
The price is: 7.99
----
The title is: Romeo And Juliet
The qty is: 5
The price is: 5.99
```

I'm very new to dictionaries and can't understand how you can sort a dictionary. My code so far is this:

```
def displayInventory(theInventory):
    theInventory = readDatabase(theInventory)
    for key in theInventory:
        for num in theInventory[key]:
            print("The author is", ' '.join(str(n) for n in key))
            print(' '.join(str(n) for n in num), '\n')
```

The dictionary, when printed, from which I read this looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('Shakespeare', 'William'): [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'], ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']], ('Dickens', 'Charles'): [['Hard Times', '7', '27.00']]})
```

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently orderless, so you wouldn't sort them. This related question seems to have produced a pretty good answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value
The idea would be to produce a list from the dictionary contents and sort that.

Comment: I asked incorrectly the first time. I have included the list that I made in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fwiw, camelCase is very uncommon in Python; almost everything is written in snake_case.  :)

I would do this:

```
for names, books in sorted(inventory.items()):
    for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
        print("The author is {0}".format(", ".join(names)))
        print(
            "The book is {0}, and I've got {1} of them for {2} each"
            .format(title, qty, price))
        print()
```

Ignoring for the moment that [not everyone has a first and last name](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

There are some minor tricks involved here.

- First, `inventory.items()` produces a list of `key, value` tuples.  I can then sort that directly, because tuples sort element-wise — that is, `(1, "z")` sorts before `(2, "a")`.  So Python will compare the keys first, and the keys are tuples themselves, so it'll compare last names and then first names.  Exactly what you want.
- I can likewise sort `books` directly because I actually want to sort by title, and the title is the first thing in each structure.
- I can `.join` the `names` tuple directly, because I already know everything in it should be a string, and something is wrong if that's not the case.
- Then I use `.format()` everywhere because `str()` is a bit ugly.

Comment: Is there a way to format this to view an author's work specifically? And if the author is not in the dictionary, will that raise an error?

Comment: well, you could move the inner loop into a function, and do `books = inventory["Shakespeare", "William"]` to get the right list of books.  and yes you'll get a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use sorted() to sort the dictionary by its keys, but then use sort() on the dictionaries values. This is necessary because your values are actually a list of lists and it seems you want only to sort them by the first value in each sub-list.

```
theInventory = {('Shakespeare', 'William'): [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'], ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']], ('Dickens', 'Charles'): [['Hard Times', '7', '27.00']]}

for Author in sorted(theInventory.keys()):
    Author_Last_First = Author[0]+", "+Author[1]
    Titles = theInventory[Author]
    Titles.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    for Title in Titles:
        print("Author: "+str(Author_Last_First))
        print("Title: "+str(Title[0]))
        print("Qty: "+str(Title[1]))
        print("Price: "+str(Title[2]))
        print("\n")
```

Is that what you had in mind? You can of course always put this in a function to make calling it easier.

Comment: `.sort` means you mutate the original dict, which may be impolite.  tuple unpacking is much easier to follow than explicit indexing.  you don't need `.keys()`; iterating a dict directly produces its keys.  and `Capital_Underscores` is really weird  :)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts :) Why would you prefer .format() to str()?

Comment: `str()` and concatenation requires breaking your string up into pieces, whereas a format string lets you see roughly what the result looks like at a glance.  `.format` is also easier to wrap by virtue of being a method.  and concatenation is O(n²), not that it matters a whole lot here